Moving stacked washer/dryer over lip in the floor
I have a small laundry closet with a stacked washer/dryer. The floor of the laundry closet is actually appreciably lower (a little less than 0.5 inches) than the floor immediately outside the closet.
I want to be able to pull them out of the closet so I can clean the dryer vent. I've read about techniques for moving the unit along the floor, but they all assume that once you get them moving they can slide right out of the closet.
I would appreciate any thoughts on how I can get over this little lip.



lift the front of the appliance

It is simple to say slide to the lip of the flooring and lift.  However the reality is that these units are bulky and heavy.  I'm a grown man in fairly good shape and I injured my shoulder doing the exact thing you want to do.  The space is limited so ramps are of little use. Either hire a company that will come in and move and clean the vent. Or hire, or use some muscular people to move it out and back in for you.

remove the top appliance first

And once you get the washer & dryer out, I would think about adding another layer of flooring where they sit to bring the floor of the closet up to that of the room, or hallway.

Lean it to the right an put something under the left side side, lean it to the right and put something under the left side. Repeat until the piles of something are taller than the thickness of the floor covering, then slide it out.
Strips of 1/8"  MDF might work well for "something". But anything long flat and reasonably rigid should work.

Lift and pull. It may seem like a flippant answer, but that's really it. How you do it depends on who's helping and what tools you have available.
Lift with a lever of some sort. A carpenter's flatbar would work well, as would any steel bar of robust construction. Pry only on the underside of the cabinet, and not on the face panel. (You might be able to simply tilt the whole thing back once you pull it forward a bit.)
Pull however you can. A rope around the bottom of the unit might help. So would an assistant.
It might also help to use some slats to clear the ledge. Lift or tilt the front feet and slide them under. Now when you pull it should naturally slide over the ledge.


Get an appliance lift kit and some appliance sliders
Remove your vent connection
Use the tool to bring it to the edge of the floor. Pull the appliance forward, tilt it up and use the tool to pull it forward over the lip.
Tilt the appliance back to place the appliance sliders under the front legs.
Use the tool to pull the appliance forward and clear the lip.
Tilt the appliance forward and place the appliance sliders on the back legs.
If possible, extend your engineered floor.
Slide the unit back in.
Reattach your vent.


Even with the appliance lift kit, it will be a struggle to get the unit over the lip of the flooring.  After that, sure the rest is elementary.

I had luck recently using PVC pipes to get my washer into a drip/drain pan. Granted, my unit is not stacked, and I’m not sure how secure your top appliance is, so proceed at your own risk. This method involves tipping the appliance enough to slide a pipe underneath, which may not be safe with a stacked unit.
Essentially, you tip the washer back and then slide a PVC pipe underneath and then use it as a roller to move the unit along. Ideally, you may want to use more than one in your case, potentially having one of a smaller diameter on the raised surface.
Especially with a stacked unit, I do not recommend doing this alone as you do not want a heavy appliance like this falling and crushing you. Ensure that the unit is secure and that it can be tipped safely.

And depending on the appliance weight, likely substantial with a stack, you might want steel pipe rollers or a solid wooden dowel (old broomhandle?) rather than a PVC pipe rollers which may crush.

Lift and pull might not work for you unless you are a weight lifter.
Go to store and buy fitting Wedge and place it as a ramp and just pull.
To make it easier with pulling, run a rope behind as low as you can place it, now you can have two people pulling.
Not to forget, pull it forward few inches, so you can reach and disconnect
wedge
